# Call another object's touches begin iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uitouch

Lets say I have view1 which is intercepting touch events and view2 which is not.

Can view1 pass those events to view2 and call [view2 touchesBegin] [view2 touchesMoved]...etc?

Comment: Have you tried it? My gut reaction is it will work, but could easily lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, sometimes, maybe. The technique you're asking about is known as **event forwarding**. I'll refer you to the [Forwarding Touch Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW17) section of the [*Event Handling Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW7), which says the following:

> The classes of the UIKit framework are not designed to receive touches
>   that are not bound to them; in programmatic terms, this means that the
>   view property of the UITouch object must hold a reference to the
>   framework object in order for the touch to be handled. If you want to
>   conditionally forward touches to other responders in your application,
>   all of these responders should be instances of your own subclasses of
>   UIView.

So, if you're looking to forward events from one view to another and both views are instances of your own UIView subclass, event forwarding may work for you. If your `view2` is an instance of a UIKit class, though -- say, UIScrollView or UITextView, you shouldn't be surprised to encounter problems. And even if it works now, it could easily break in the future. A little further on in the text, that section states this more simply:

> Do not forward events to UIKit framework objects.

I'd urge you to read the entire section -- there's some good advice and an example that may help if you do decide to use event forwarding.

Comment: Just came across your answer, the **Forward Touch Events** link has moved to: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW7

Comment: @MikeD Thanks for pointing it out. I updated the link, but Apple still tries to redirect it to a less useful page.